# farsi chars in codeigniter active records error

Tags: php, codeigniter, persian, farsi

I try to grab some data via active records in codeigniter by this model (page_model.php):

```
class Page_model extends CI_model{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function get_content($page){
        var_dump($page);
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pages', array('name' => $page));
        var_dump($query);
        if($query->num_rows()<1){
            echo $page;
            return FALSE;
        }
        else{
//          foreach($query->result() as $row){
//              $data[]=$row;
//          }
//          return $data;
    return $data=$query->result();

        }

    }
}
```

and contents.php view :

```
<div class="contents">
<?php 
foreach($info as $p){
    $c= $p->content;
}
echo $c;


?>
</div>
```

pages.php controller :

```
<?php 
class Pages extends CI_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('page_model');
    }
    public function index($page){
        echo strlen("س");
        $data['info']=$this->page_model->get_content("ایران");
        var_dump($data['info']);
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('contents',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

and it gives me this error :

```
 PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/contents.php

Line Number: 3

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: c

Filename: views/contents.php

Line Number: 6
```

var_dump($page) :

```
string 'ایران' (length=10)
```

var_dump($query) :

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)[16]
  public 'conn_id' => resource(29, mysql link persistent)
  public 'result_id' => resource(32, mysql result)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'row_data' => null
```

var_dump($info):

```
boolean false
```

but I have a record with column name="ایران"
and I set permited_url_chars to empty.

thank you

Comment: what is the output of: `var_dump($data['info']);`?

Comment: Thank you. Please specify the values of all the other var_dumps in your code.

Comment: Which charset does the file `pages.php` have? And which charset is defined in your database?

Comment: I edited the question , added var_dumps results.

Comment: dear vstm , database is utf8_persian_ci , and the page is utf8

Comment: You need to set the charset and collation properly in the database configuration file. (application/config/database.php)

Comment: Also, please let us know the output of `echo $this->db->last_query();` (insert this line after the `var_dump($query);` line)

Comment: I found the problem and solved it , dear J.Bruni , thanks for your answer